# Remove terrain shadow in Landsat image in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, landsat

I'm trying to extract water located in mountainous areas using Landsat satellite images in GEE. But the method I used will misclassify terrain shadow as water. I try to use DEM to remove terrain shadow, however, there are some errors in my code.

Here is the code:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  [[100.6636076429711,26.655075483873333], 
  [98.75836472304923,26.655075483873333],
  [98.75836472304923,22.839494424963217], 
  [100.6636076429711,22.839494424963217], 
  [100.6636076429711,26.655075483873333]]]);

Map.centerObject(roi)

var sDate_T1 = "2014-01-01";
 
var eDate_T1 = "2014-12-31"; 

var bn8 = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B6', 'pixel_qa', 'B5', 'B7'];

var bn7 = ['B1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B5', 'pixel_qa', 'B4', 'B7'];

var bns = ['uBlue', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'Swir1', 'BQA', 'Nir', 'Swir2'];

var ls7 = (ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR")
  .filterDate('1999-04-15', '2003-05-30')
  .select(bn7, bns));

var ls8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR").select(bn8, bns);

var merged = ls7.merge(ls8);

var Ndvi = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['Nir', 'Red']).rename('ndvi');
  return(ndvi);
};

var Mndwi = function(image) {
  var mndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['Green', 'Swir1']).rename('mndwi');
  return(mndwi);
};

var Evi = function(image) {
  var evi = image.expression('2.5 * (Nir - Red) / (1 + Nir + 6 * Red - 7.5 * Blue)', {
    'Nir': image.select(['Nir']),
    'Red': image.select(['Red']),
    'Blue': image.select(['Blue'])
    });
  return(evi.rename(['evi']));
};

var params_true = {crs: 'EPSG:4326', region: roi, min: 0.0, max: 0.3, bands: ["Red", "Green", "Blue"], dimensions: 1000};

var waterViz = {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['white', 'blue']};

var imgCloud = merged.filterDate(sDate_T1, eDate_T1) 
                 .filterBounds(roi)
                 .map(function(image) { 
                    var cloudsBitMask = 1 << 3; 
                    var cloudShadowBitMask = 1 << 4;
                    var snowBitMask = 1 << 5; 
                    var qa = image.select('BQA'); 
                    var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0) 
                                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0))
                                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(snowBitMask).eq(0)); 
                    return image.updateMask(mask).multiply(0.0001).clip(roi)
                   }); 

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

var dem = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');

function hillshade(image) {
  var elevation = dem.clip(roi)
  var azimuth = image.getNumber('SUN_AZIMUTH')
  var zenith = ee.Number(100).subtract(image.getNumber('SUN_ELEVATION'))
  var shaded_relief = ee.Terrain.hillShadow(elevation, azimuth, zenith)
  return image.updateMask(shaded_relief);
}

var imgCol = imgCloud.map(hillshade);

function shade(image) {
  var elevation = dem.clip(roi)
  var azimuth = image.getNumber('SUN_AZIMUTH')
  var zenith = ee.Number(100).subtract(image.getNumber('SUN_ELEVATION'))
  var shaded_relief = ee.Terrain.hillShadow(elevation, azimuth, zenith)
  return image.updateMask(shaded_relief.not());
}

var hillshademask = imgCloud.map(shade);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

var bnp50 = ['uBlue_p50', 'Blue_p50', 'Green_p50', 'Red_p50', 'Swir1_p50', 'BQA_p50', 'Nir_p50', 'Swir2_p50'];

var p50 = imgCol.reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([50])).select(bnp50, bns);

var mndwi_p50 = Mndwi(p50);

var ndvi_p50 = Ndvi(p50);

var evi_p50 = Evi(p50);

var water_p50 = (mndwi_p50.gt(ndvi_p50).or(mndwi_p50.gt(evi_p50))).and(evi_p50.lt(0.1));

var waterMasked_p50 = water_p50.updateMask(water_p50.gt(0));

var True_colour = p50.select(["Red", "Green", "Blue"]);

var Wetted_channel = waterMasked_p50;

Map.addLayer(True_colour.clip(roi), params_true, 'True colour temporal composite', false);

Map.addLayer(hillshademask.median().clip(roi), params_true, 'hillshade mask', false);

Map.addLayer(Wetted_channel, waterViz, 'Wetted channel', false)

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The error is displayed as:

> Layer error: ImageCollection.reduce: Error in map(ID=null):
> Number.subtract: Parameter 'right' is required.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the images within [the image collection you are using](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C01_T1_SR#image-properties) don't have the `SUN_ELEVATION` or `SUN_AZIMUTH` properties. More importantly, that image collection is deprecated, in favor of the [Collection 02](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2):

```js
var bn8 = ['SR_B1', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B6', 'QA_PIXEL', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B7'];

var bn7 = ['SR_B1', 'SR_B1', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B5', 'QA_PIXEL', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B7'];

var bns = ['uBlue', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'Swir1', 'BQA', 'Nir', 'Swir2'];

var ls7 = (ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2")
  .filterDate('1999-04-15', '2003-05-30')
  .select(bn7, bns));

var ls8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2").select(bn8, bns);
```

Another problem is that `ee.Image.multiply()` doesn't keep properties, e.g.:

```js
var foo = ee.Image(1).set({"property":"bar"})
print(foo)
print(foo.multiply(1))   // Doesn't show the property "bar"
print(foo.multiply(1).copyProperties(foo))
```

At the same time, because you will be using C02 instead of C01, the scaling factors are different. So you can add `.copyProperties` and update the scaling factors in the same line:

```js
var imgCloud = merged.filterDate(sDate_T1, eDate_T1) 
                 .filterBounds(roi)
                 .map(function(image) { 
                    var cloudsBitMask = 1 << 3; 
                    var cloudShadowBitMask = 1 << 4;
                    var snowBitMask = 1 << 5; 
                    var qa = image.select('BQA'); 
                    var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0) 
                                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0))
                                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(snowBitMask).eq(0)); 
                    return image.updateMask(mask).multiply(2.75e-05).add(-0.2).clip(roi).copyProperties(image)
                   });
```

Here is the complete code with these changes:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/fb057ca8d7e984a4857d8336c249ebee

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! The problem has been solved.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Would you mind marking the answer as accepted?

Comment: Certainly. How should I mark the answer as accepted? Sorry I don't know how to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Oh I get it now. Thanks!